# Qt 5.12.11 installation crashes on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: qt, ubuntu-18.04

I've download **Qt for Open Source Development** online installation file named as **qt-unified-linux-x64-4.1.1-online.run**

I edited the file property just to execute the file as a program. I let the program doing the installation, but after a few minutes later, it just crashes: Error during installation process (qt.qt5.512211.src).

I have several libraries and programs like Arduino; web servers like ngninx, or php, phpMyAdmin, mySQL and all of them run ok. Qt is the only one with issues.

[image]

It could be a bug from Qt? Or should I reinstall Ubuntu 18.04 and do all the Qt installation process again?

Comment: Check with your QT resources.  They should be able to quickly assist.

Comment: I suspect that you might have not enough space for installation — either in the target FS, or in `/tmp`. Too bad the installer wasn't able to diagnose the actual reason of its failure...